# cyclic galois group

Tags: galois-theory

let K be any field and $\sigma$ be an automorphism of of K where F is the fixed field of $\sigma$ and order of $\sigma$ is "s". now to prove is that [K:F] = s.

well if look at Gal(K/F) it contain all powers of $\sigma$ , so s elements are in it namely {$\sigma$, $\sigma^2$, $\sigma^3$,..., $\sigma^s$ = 1}. but also we know |Gal(K/F)| divides 
[K:F] and equal iff K/F is galois extension.

so my doubt here is first of all why Gal(K/F) is cyclic and second why K/F is Galois? if these two happen, we are through.

i know i am missing something trivial here. it has been a while i did Galois theory, actually this doubt came in non commutative rings. any hints or ideas or cf.

Comment: I'm assume you're implicitly assuming $s<\infty$ based on how you've written the question.

Overall, this is basically the definition of fixed fields for automorphisms. Decompose $K/F$ into a separable and purely inseparable extension, get that the inseparable degree is 1, proving separability. Then normality is easy using the primitive element theorem and linear independence of the characters.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $x\in K$, and let $\{x_0, \dots, x_{r-1}\}$ denote the orbit of $x$ under $\sigma$ for some $r\leq s$, where $x_i = \sigma^i(x)$. Then the polynomial $f(X) = \prod_{i < r} (X - x_i)\in F[X]$, since the coefficients of $f$ are symmetric polyomials in the $\sigma^i(x)$. Since all the $x_i\not\in F$ are distinct, $f$ is irreducible. It follows that $K/F$ is Galois (assuming $s$ is finite). Since $F$ is the fixed field of $G = \langle{\sigma}\rangle\subset \text{Gal}(K/F)$, we then have $[K:F] = \#G = s$.

Comment: thanks a lot. nice proof. this means $\{x_0, \dots, x_{s-1}\}$ is the F basis for K. i guessed that correct, but trouble was to see how do they span K. This is something on which if you could suggest something will be great.

Comment: It's not a basis for an arbitrary $x\in K$ (take $x\in F$, for example), but it follows from counting degrees if, for example, $K = F(x)$.